DotnetCore Blazor Wasm Hosted, does not serve the static files
I have a dotnet core hosted blazor web application, I am using kestrel for server management. When I build the application using visual studio and copy it to a linux server, the static files are served when I make the request to the specified port. However, when I build the application from the terminal, the static files are not served, I can see my swagger though. This is my command for the build.
dotnet build -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained --output Release/Publish/LinuxVersion

I am not sure what the issue is, but please any help would be appreciated.
